# PHP Merge Array Subkeys

Tags: php

I've seen several questions and answers on this but none that seem to do what I need.  Basically I have:

Array1:

```
[2014-1-1]
    [0]
        'goodthings' = 9
```

Array2:

```
[2014-1-1]
    [0]
        'badthings' = 2
```

and I want to create:

resultarray:

```
[2014-1-1]
    [0]
        'goodthings' = 9
        'badthings' = 2
```

Where [2014-1-1] is a list of dates and [0] is the hours of the day... Seems like a simple request but I can't figure it out?

Comment: Have you tried `array_merge()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Pls, show the output of `var_dump()` or `print_r()` for both original and result arrays

Comment: [array_merge_recursive()](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Comment: from the resultarray it seems you are after string concatenation, specially if the inner key `[0]` has a meaning...

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if this is exactly what you want, but

Using [array_merge_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

```
$array1 = [
    '2014-1-1' => [
        0 => ['goodthings' => 9]
    ]
];

$array2 = [
    '2014-1-1' => [
        0 => ['badthings' => 2]
    ]
];

$result = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
var_dump($result);
```

gives

```
[ "2014-1-1" => [
    0 => [ "goodthings" => 9 ]
    1 => [ "badthings" => 2 ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you Mark that's very close, but each integer represents an hour of the day so I need the end result to like: 0-->goodthings, badthings  1--> goodthings, badthings ... etc   .... frustrating one lol